# 000webhost #1045 - Access denied for user 'a6481343_abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: web-services, phpmyadmin

I just created an account. Created a mysql instance and when i try to access it via phpmyadmin it keeps on giving me this message and asking for a password. I have tried every password nothing works. I even created a new instance of mysql but still didn't work.

Comment: It may be a firewall issue. Are you running PHPMyAdmin on the same instance? Are you sure that the MySQL DB password is the one you are using?

Comment: Same thing here... I've just created a new instance, already tried to change the database password, and I always get that same error!